# How to recalculate the automatic weights for single bones in blender 2.8

Tags: bones, weight-painting, vertex-weights

I'm trying to weight paint correctly and quickly a 3D character in Blender 2.8. I have rigged it with **auto-rig-pro** and then I used the addon "**Voxel and Surface Heat Diffuse Skinning**" for the weight painting. It did a good job,except for the teeth. Infact when I open it,this is what happens :

[image: 1]

Since I've switched to blender 2.8 recently,I still have to learn it. I would like to **recalculate the automatic weights only for the bones** which have a wrong weight. So,I pressed the **W key**,but I don't see the entry "**Assign automatic from bones**". Where is it ?

[image: 2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will find it in the Weights menu. Upper left corner of the 3D view.